# Hide or Show Product By Customer or Customer Group in Listing Page (magento 1.9)

Tags: php, magento-1.9

**Hide or Show Particular Product By Customer or Customer Group in Listing Page (magento 1.9)**

I add the Back order Products those product only visible the particular customer. How to i do in magento 1.9? Plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can observe **catalog_product_collection_apply_limitations_after** event, assuming you have a product attribute to filter according your desired logic

So, in your observer...

```
public function yourmethod($observer){

    // here you have customer object
    $currentUser = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

    // your logic here, so let's say you get
    // $yourFilteredValue for 'your_attribute'
    // based in $currentUser data

    // and then... the filter
    $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('your_attribute',array('eq'=> $yourFilteredValue));
}
```

Feel free to join https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions & post more details about what you want

Comment: Hai Raul Sanchez,

Comment: i need the backorder Product Hide the Particular customer in listing Page. This is working for Me?

Comment: Invalid method MageFe_Backorder_Model_Product::addAttributeToFilter(Array
(
    [0] => setVisibility
    [1] => Array
        (
            [eq] => 1
        )

)
)
these error displayed